# Cannot signin using HttpContext.SignInAsync

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-mvc-3, authorization

I'm developing an application using ASP.Net Core MVC 3.1 and i am facing a problem where it fails to sign-in. localhost response 401 unauthorized

AccountController

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(PixClient client)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>();
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, client.Email));
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(principal));
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

Startup.cs

```
 services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/account/login";
            options.Cookie.Name = "sessionid";

        });
```

Index.cs

```
 [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Index()
    { ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the codes you've shown,there's no mistake in it.
Make sure you've added the Authentication middleware and it was in correct order:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            .......
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();
            ......
        }
```

And you could create a middleware to check if the ticked is generated and added to cookie successfully:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) => 
            {
                var cookies = context.Request.Cookies;
                await next.Invoke();
            });
```

I tried as below:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie( m =>
            {
                m.LoginPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/Home/Login");
                m.Cookie.Name = "CookieAuth";
               
            });
```

When redirect to `/Home/Login`,you could see the cookie named`CookieAuth`:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much man, i tried so many things i almost gave up